# Android: LinearLayout with text and Icon

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:azeoo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/opening_today_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opening_today"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="A standard line" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/opening_today"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]

But if I put a long text for "opening_today" like for exemple "A very very very long line with a lot of texts with ellipsize end", the ImageView disappears:

[image]

So, how can I do to **keep** the ImageView even the text has a big size ?

Comment: There is a `drawableRight` attribute to a Textview. You don't need a separate ImageView

Comment: Why don't you use a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This it may be helpful to you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:azeoo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/opening_today_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opening_today"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="A very very very long line with a lot of texts with ellipsize end" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no your case is not correct for my first result with "A standard line" text.

Comment: You should also This in relative layout. android:gravity="left"

Comment: In absolute way, How can I resolve my first problem with TextView and ImageView ?

Comment: @anthony above solution is for both of your problem

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/opening_today_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opening_today"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="A standard lffsdfsfsdfsfsfhgf fkhh gkjhg hkgj jhg hjgk jhg jkgjhg kjh jhgkj gkjsfsfsdfsdfsfsfdfdfdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsfdsdfsdfsfsfine"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As **cricket_007** said in its comment you can reference the image direclty within the `TextView` tag using `android:drawableRight`

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:azeoo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/opening_today_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opening_today"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="A standard line A standard line A standard line A standard line A standard line"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Doing this you cannot specify anymore the image height and width as in your initial code. Just be sure to have the correct image size into all your `res/drawable` folders.

Comment: How can I custom this drawable (size and color) ?

Comment: Regarding how to "customize" size you can find information here http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html